# Edit all the values in a column in SQL

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I can't find anything about this on the web.

I need to edit all values in a column in my database but I can't find a way.

I'm doing:

```
if (upgradeCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                db.editListsColumn("0");
            } while (upgradeCursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Where upgradeCursor:

```
    return mDb.query(ProductsData.PRODUCTS_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And editListsColumn("0"):

```
public void editListsColumn(String lists) {
    mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ProductsMetaData.PRODUCT_PRODUCT, lists);
    mDb.update(ProductsData.PRODUCTS_TABLE, cv, "lists=?", null);
}
```

I'm stuck here.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated at the moment! Thank you so much.

Comment: `This isn't working` - ???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a simple update without the where clause and without iterating the cursor. What I mean is simply call this:

```
mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ProductsMetaData.PRODUCT_PRODUCT, lists);
mDb.update(ProductsData.PRODUCTS_TABLE, cv, null, null);
```

Without:

```
if (upgradeCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                db.editListsColumn("0");
            } while (upgradeCursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

From the documentation of the `update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` method: *passing `NULL` in `whereClause` will update all rows*.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html